# How to close an instance of file explorer using python?

Tags: windows-explorer, python, task-manager, wmi

I have 3 instances of File Explorer running on my system. In the task manager, there is only a single process_id assigned to explorer.exe
So if i want to kill one particular instance of explorer window using python, how can I do so? How can I uniquely identify any instance of explorer.exe so that i can use the terminate method in wmi package.

Comment: I'd assume you have to use python bindings for the win32 api to send a WM_CLOSE message after you identify the correct window via some criterias (windows name, window class), never did it but check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728081/anyway-to-get-a-window-handle-by-its-title-using-win32-api

Answer (score 0):

You can use [taskkill](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb491009(v=technet.10)) and the Python [os.system()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system):

```
import os
os.system("taskkill /pid <ProcessID>")
```

Comment: Hello,
When I open several instances of file explorers, there is only a single pid for all the instances in the task manager.
So how can I identify the explorer window that I want to open?